# VMWare 11 on Ubuntu 15 install failed

Tags: vmware, 15.10

Using `VMWare 11` on `Ubuntu 15` fails when installing components, because of `kernel`

Help

Comment: Yes, I answered my own question because it took some time to put together the full solution and the problem is pretty big

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by applying a patch and modifying 1 extra parameter.

1. Run as `root` the following commands

   ```
   curl http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
   cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
   tar -xf vmnet.tar
   patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
   mv vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.SAVED
   tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
   rm -r vmnet-only63
   vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
   ```
2. Now, you need one more patch and everything will work (as `root`)

   ```
   cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
   sudo tar -xf vmnet.tar
   sudo joe vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h
   ```
3. in line 82, add a trailing ",1" just as in line 84

   ```
   old: PF_NETLINK, _pri, &vmnet_proto)
   new: PF_NETLINK, _pri, &vmnet_proto, 1)
   ```
4. save everything back to .tar

   ```
   sudo tar -uf vmnet.tar vmnet-only/vmnetInt.h
   ```
5. Run and enjoy

**Note:** if it sill fails try adding dependencies for `i:386`. They are needed to install windows

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```